# How can I create a Circle with a small notch at bottom in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a circle on co-ordinate plane and fill the pixels in it with conditional colors. However, the circle also need to show a small triangular notch at the bottom from the center. Something like the attached picture.

I have used the matplotlib's patches class to create acircle and tried different values in attributes but of no help. I googled enough but I couldn't find it.

`circle = matplotlib.patches.Circle((0,0),150,facecolor='lightgrey')
ax.add_patch(circle)`

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OVHZ.png)

Can someone please help me or provide me a hint or direct me to right library which can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like 2D vector graphics which in this case you should look for SVG

if it is a CAD problem then you can check some CAD libraries
 - [Python module for parametric CAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519057/python-module-for-parametric-cad)

I think CAD approach is much better for engineering operations which you can find https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Part_Slice and https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Part_SliceApart#Scripting

or for SVG approach found something: https://inkscape.org/~Moini/%E2%98%85multi-bool-extension-cut-difference-division

If you have to do that in mathplotlib then you can export/import vector graphics into plots

Comment: Thank you Abdurrahim, I will read more about vector graphics. Appreciate you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build the proposed shape using parametric equations.
There are some approximations, but if you get the exact geometry equations you could refine this to a better version.

In fact, the key is to define the *correct equations* ... the ideal case would be to ensure continuity.

*This example has some caveats: approximations when joining the 2 circles due to geometrical simplification when drawing the small circle from `pi` to `0`. Small circle start/end angles should be chosen as the interception of the 2 full circles for a more accurate shape continuity. But again, in the end it depends entirely on your shape specification*

Heavly inspired from [Plot equation showing a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092899/plot-equation-showing-a-circle)

[image]

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def compute_x_values(r, theta):
    return r * np.cos(theta)


def compute_y_values(r, theta):
    return r * np.sin(theta)


def compute_circle(r, theta):
    return compute_x_values(r, theta), compute_y_values(r, theta)


def build_big_circle(crop_angle, offset, radius):
    start_angle = offset + crop_angle
    end_angle = offset + (2 * np.pi) - crop_angle
    theta = np.linspace(start_angle, end_angle, 250)
    # compute main circle vals
    x, y = compute_circle(radius, theta)
    return x, y


r = 1
offset = - np.pi / 2
crop_angle = np.pi / 20
x, y = build_big_circle(crop_angle, offset, r)

# now the other form:
# its a half circle from pi to 0
theta2 = np.linspace(np.pi, 0, 100)

# according our code above, angular space left on the circle for the notch is
missing_angle = crop_angle * 2

# the length between to points on a circle is given by the formula
# length = 2 * r * sin(angle/2)
l = math.sin(missing_angle / 2) * r * 2

# we want half the length for a future radius
r2 = l / 2

# the above lines could be optimized to this
# r2 = math.sin(crop_angle) * r
# but I kept intermediate steps for sake of geometric clarity

# equation is same of a circle
x1, y1 = compute_circle(r2, theta2)

# change center on y axis to - big circle radius
y1 = y1 - r

# merge the 2
x_total = np.append(x, x1)
y_total = np.append(y, y1)

# create the global figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x_total, y_total)
ax.fill(x_total, y_total, facecolor='lightgrey', linewidth=1)
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(x1, y1)
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much LoneWanderer. It is what I am looking for. I, Appreciate your help.